# C++ Check if wchar_t is in wchar_t array

Tags: c++, arrays, wchar-t

I am stuck with some Code of C++:

```
    wchar_t *str1 = L"foo"
    wchar_t *str2[] = {L"foo", L"another_value" };
```

Now what I am looking for is to find out if array str2 contains str1. I hope you can help me.

Best regards

Comment: `std::any_of(str2, str2 + 2, [str1](const wchar_t* elem) { return wcscmp(elem, str1) == 0; });`

Comment: explanation please?

Comment: Which part do you find unclear, and were unable to clarify with the help of your handy C++ reference?

Comment: does it return true/false if str1 is in str2?

Comment: [The documentation for `std::any_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) should be able to answer this question.

Comment: `wchar_t *str1 = L"foo"` should issue at least a warnning as it is non standard.  You should be using `wchar_t str1[] = L"foo"`

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik - He may also find your use of a lambda expression as the predicate to be unclear. Another reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda